# Best way to implement SCD1 in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a master table (~100mm records) which needs to be updated/inserted with daily delta that gets processed every day.

Typical daily volume for delta would be few hundred thousand records. This can be implemented using `full join` or windowing function `row_number+union` all.

But my question is which out of these two is a better approach to go for using Hive (it’s running on Tez and the version is 2.1). We want to update all fields in master for a record which has a change in delta so would like to go with `row_number+union` all and looking for some optimization strategies.

Answer (score 0):

I think general rule of thumb is- avoid full joins - always.

I don't know how do you mean to use windowing function with union, but in my experience the following worked quite well (assuming join matches 1:1):

**Full join**

```sql
select 
    coalesce(x.a, y.a) as a,
    coalesce(x.b, y.b) as b,
    coalesce(x.c, y.c) as c,
    coalesce(x.d, y.d) as d,
    x.xe,
    y.ye
from
    x
full outer join y 
    on x.a=y.a and x.b=y.b
```

**Union**

```sql
select 
    a,
    b,
    coalesce(max(x_c), max(y_c)) as c,
    coalesce(max(x_d), max(y_d)) as d,
    max(xe) as xe,
    max(ye) as ye
from
    (select a,b,c as x_c,d as x_d, null as y_c, null as y_d, xe, null as ye from x
    union all 
     select a,b,null as x_c, null as x_d, c as y_c, d as y_d, null as xe, ye from y) main
group by 
    a,b
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `explain  your_sql;` to observe the execution plan for the queries you're comparing.

For the case of implementing SCD1, `full join` and `row_number+union` yields very similar plan, both containing just one stage of map-reduce. So there's no obvious performance difference.

But do note there's more flexibility you can get out of `full join`.